# Given a sample of random variables, and n, how do I find the ecdf of the sum of n Xs?

Tags: r

I can't fit `X` to a common distribution so currently I just have `X ~ ecdf(sample_data)`.

How do I calculate the empirical distribution of `sum(X1 + ... + Xn)`, given `n`? X1 to Xn are iid.

Comment: Wait....you have `n` random variables (who knows whether or not they're iid), and you want to find the distribution of their sum?

Comment: Without more information, I don't believe there is a way to determine the distribution of the sum of these variables.

Comment: So, I've picked two iid random variables...tell me how their sum is distributed.

Comment: Ok, just for understanding: You have some data, estimate a distribution function just by using the empirical distribution, call this distribution `X` and now want to compute the distribution of `sum(X_i)` with `i=1,...,n` for a given `n` and `X_i ~ X`?

Comment: So, I've chosen two iid random variables, let's call them `X` and `Y` (so, for simplicity's sake, `n==2`).  Tell me how `X+Y` is distributed.

Comment: @Thilo - yes I believe you understand.

Comment: I think I do, but I'm not sure if you do, so I'll spell it out: you need more information to determine the distribution of the sum.  If each of the (iid) `X_i` are normal, then their sum is normal.  If they're all zero, then their sum is zero.  **You can't determine the distribution of the sum given nothing more than the number of variables and the fact that the variables are iid**.

Comment: @Jack [sum of two rvs](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~susan/courses/s116/node114.html) As I have the _empirical_ densities, I can also numerically calculate the dist. of the sum empirically. (NB. one can calculate an integral numerically)

Comment: Sure...you go ahead and have fun with that.  While you're at it, go ahead and *empirically* square a circle, double a cube, and trisect an angle.

Comment: @Jack I fell you did not understand the question. He estimated a distribution function from some data. His question is now how to compute the distribution function of the sum of variables based on his estimated function. While I fear you can get in a lot of statistical troubles depending on the accuracy of the first estimate, I feel the question itself is absolutely legit.

Comment: As your question is more about statistical methods than actual implementation, I feel the question is more suited at stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: I dont think it is about stat methods, IMHO it feels like a straightforward computation. Indeed, I do know the stats behind it (it is explained in the link above). I just need to know how to compute that integral in R.

Comment: In that case, you have N vectors `X1` thru `XN`  so you've got a N-tuple integral (sum) to calculate.  Isn't the formula at [discreteRV](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~susan/courses/s116/node112.html)  what you want?

Comment: I'm modelling a continuous rv, so I'm using calculus. Of course the discrete formulae are analogous to the continuous, and indeed the numerical approximation to the continuous is basically the discrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To estimate the distribution of that sum, you can repeatedly sample with replacement (and then take the sum of) `n` variates from `sample_data`. (`sample()` places equal probability mass on each element of `sample_data`, just as the ecdf does, so you don't need to calculate `ecdf(sample_data)` as an intermediate step.)

```
# Create some example data
sample_data <- runif(100)

n <- 10
X <- replicate(1000, sum(sample(sample_data, size=n, replace=TRUE)))

# Plot the estimated distribution of the sum of n variates.
hist(X, breaks=40, col="grey", main=expression(sum(x[i], i==1, n)))
box(bty="l")

# Plot the ecdf of the sum
plot(ecdf(X))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, generalize and simplify: solve for step function CDFs X and Y, independent but not identically distributed. For every step jump x<sub>i</sub> and every step jump y<sub>i</sub>, there will be a corresponding step jump at x<sub>i</sub>+y<sub>i</sub> in the CDF of X + Y, So the CDF of X + Y will be characterized by the list:

```
sorted(x + y for x in X for y in Y)
```

That means if there are k points in X's CDF, there will be k<sup>n</sup> in (X<sub>1</sub> + ... + X<sub>n</sub>). We can cut that down to a manageable number at the end by throwing away all but k again, but clearly the intermediate calculations will be costly in time and space.

Also, note that even though the original CDF is an ECDF for X, the result will *not* be an ECDF for (X<sub>1</sub> + ... + X<sub>n</sub>), even if you keep all k<sup>n</sup> points.

In conclusion, use Josh's solution.